# MSGraph, REST API: get versioning setting for a SharePoint 365 library?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the versioning settings for an SP365 library using MS Graph REST API. Primarily interested in must-checkout setting; would be nice if there's a method to get them all.

These settings are under [Library Settings/VersioningSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s0sB.png)

Thanks in advance!

NS

Comment: What have you tried so far? In order to help you we need to konw what you have tried, what the result is and any errors

Comment: @SimonPrice - I tried reading the MS Graph docs :) There doesn't seem to be an obvious REST endpoint to obtain these settings. I tried the endpoint that get the drive item data, but that doesn't return any of these settings. I have a working app that supports CRUD on SP365 data. I need to add function that determines whether I need to check out a drive item before updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in MS Graph API those properties (Version settings) are not exposed via [`List`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/list) or [`Drive`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/drive) resources.

Instead you could utilize [SharePoint REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx) and in particular [`List` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_List)

Once you got *list id* from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id/lists/{list-id}`, *version settings* could be retrieved like this:

```
https://{site-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getById('{list-id}')?$select=EnableVersioning,EnableMinorVersions,EnableModeration,ForceCheckout,MajorVersionLimit,MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit,DraftVersionVisibility
```